# Validation issue in Vue with vue-signature-pad

Tags: validation, vue.js

I'm a learner and this is my very first question so please don't shoot me. Before asking this question I've been looking everywhere to a solution but wit no luck.

I've created a simple form in Vue with Vuetify and the idea is that all fields need to be filled in before you can register. Before all fields are filled in the register button is disabled.
Everything works except the validation of the signature field.

Please also tell me what I've done wrong and why I need to do it different. This is the only way I will learn.

```
    <template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card>
      <v-form ref="form" @submit.prevent="submit">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-text-field v-model="form.first" :rules="rules.fname" label="Firstname" required></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-text-field v-model="form.last" :rules="rules.lname" label="Lastname" required></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="6">
            <VueSignaturePad
              id="signature"
              width="100%"
              height="200px"
              ref="sign"
              v-model="form.sign"
              :rules="rules.sign"
              :options="{onBegin: doStartSignature }"
            />
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-checkbox v-model="form.terms" :rules="rules.terms" required color="green">
              <template v-slot:label>
                <div @click.stop>
                  Do you accept the
                  <a href="#">terms</a>
                  and
                  <a href="#">conditions?</a>
                </div>
              </template>
            </v-checkbox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-form>
      <v-btn @click="submit" :disabled="!formIsValid">Register</v-btn>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

script

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    const defaultForm = Object.freeze({
      first: "",
      last: "",
      terms: false,
      sign: true
    });

    return {
      form: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
      rules: {
        fname: [val => (val || "").length > 0 || "Firstname is required"],
        lname: [val => (val || "").length > 0 || "Lastname is required"],
        terms: [val => val || false || "Acceptance is required"],
        sign: [val => val || true || "Signature is required"]
      },
      defaultForm
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formIsValid() {
      return (
        this.form.first && this.form.last && this.form.terms && this.form.sign
      );
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submit() {
      const { isEmpty, data } = this.$refs.sign.saveSignature();
      console.log(isEmpty);
      console.log(data);
      console.log("Firstname: " + this.form.first);
      console.log("Lastname : " + this.form.last);
      console.log("Terms : " + this.form.terms);
      console.log("Signature : " + this.form.sign);
    },

    doStartSignature() {
      this.$refs.sign.resizeCanvas();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the validation rules for `terms` and `sign`:

```
terms: [val => val || false || "Acceptance is required"],
sign: [val => val || true || "Signature is required"]
```

we see that the two rules differ even though they seem to ought to have the same purpose. The `sign` rule starts with `val || true`. It will always return `true` since `true` OR'ed with anything is `true`. So even if `val` is empty, the rule will return `true` and the validation will pass.

You don't specify what exactly the "validation issue" is that you're experiencing, but if it is that you're expecting a validation error when the `signature` field is empty, then change `val || true` to `val || false`.